# Can't sign in to Windows Live from OneNote

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-account

My laptop runs on Windows 7, and this is the first time I've tried syncing my OneNote notebooks onto the web. I already have a SkyDrive account set up, but whenever I try logging into it through OneNote, it won't let me. I suspect that the problem may be that my SkyDrive account is a Gmail account, but this should not be a problem because through the SkyDrive website I can log in. Some other details that may
or may not be pertinent:

- This is OneNote 2010
- I am attempting this from a hotel wireless connection. I know that SkyDrive has measures against logging on from new places, but I've already dealt with all of this.

Thank you so much for answering what may be a "newbie" question!

Comment: Good news: The fact that you used a gmail email address means nothing for this.  having said that -- Can you please expand on "it won't let me" - what actually happens when you try? Any error messages?  Also, have you got all the latest Windows and Office 2010 updates installed?

Comment: My Microsoft Account's username also is a Google Account email, that isn't the reason you can't log into the account.  **Without the specific error we can't help**

Comment: Username or password is invalid. Again, I have no trouble logging into the SkyDrive website, only the OneNote application. Apologies since this doesn't rule out idiot mistakes without evidence, but I did enter the email and password multiple times so it can't be a typo. I emphasize that I retyped both the password and email, since I know applications have the tendency to keep your username after a failed login attempt and from the low quality of my post one could expect me to have only rewritten my password).

Answer (score 1):

> ...**two-factor authentication**.  If you have this
>   enabled, to sign into OneNote on your PC you have to use your **App**
>   **Password**, not your actual password to your Live account.  So log into
>   your Live account, Click on Security Info, and then click create a new
>   app password.  It will then display the current, or new, app password.
>   Now use that password that it gives you in OneNote and everything
>   should sign right in.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/onenote-2010-cant-connect-to-windows-live/db8bac34-d7fd-4e9a-908f-afb01e962051?auth=1